# Does exists a dolly and/or a tilt/pan motor for action cam ?

Tags: timelapse

I love doing time-lapse with my action camera.
I'd like to add some motion on it: does exists dolly and / or pan/tilt motor for action camera ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have seen people using those little alarm clocks made for the kitchen to check cooking or baking times.

Some of them have a rotating outer part which usually gets rotated to cog them.
If you attach your camera to that part it will be rotated as the clock unwinds.

The downside is that the speed of rotation is fixed, but they are pretty cheap.